# Adding custom Field to django queryset containing source record

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to add a field to a queryset in django which would do the following:

```
    fitting_set_items_list = FittingSetItem.objects.exclude(fitting_pack = None).exclude(fitting_pack = '').order_by('usage_type')
    fitting_pack_list = FittingPack.objects.filter(fittingsetitem__in=fitting_set_items_list).add_field({'fitting_set_item': fittingsetitem})
```

This way i could use:

```
for fitting_pack_item in fitting_pack_item_list:
    fitting_set_item = fitting_pack_item.fitting_set_item
```

and it'd have the FittingSetItem that i came from in the first place.

The overall Idea is that Many FittingSetItems can point to a FittingPack, so i want to be able to know which FittingSetItem my FittingPack was sourced from, and the easiest way i saw was to have the reverse FK on the FittingPack. This would allow me to go backwards and forwards on possibly ambiguous FK relations

Comment: This would be much easier to answer with your Model code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you seek, if `FittingSetItem.fitting_pack` is a `ForeignKey`

```
fitting_packs = FittingPack.objects.filter(fittingsetitem__fitting_pack__isnull=False)
```

It gets the fitting packs linked by a set item. You might add `.distinct()` or replace `fittingsetitem` with `fitting_set_item`.